# Is the WAL data text format documented anywhere?

Tags: postgresql, change-data-capture

Looking around the Web, I can find plenty of information explaining how to set up WAL replication, and [how to get the changes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding-example.html) with `pg_logical_slot_get_changes` or `pg_logical_slot_peek_changes`.  This gives a result set with 3 columns, and the third, `data`, contains the actual change data in an unusual text format.

I can't seem to find a formal specification of this format anywhere, which makes parsing it difficult.  Is the `data` format specified anywhere?  (Preferably in official Postgres documentation, but if not other sources will do.)

Comment: You can use a different output plugin, e.g. [wal2json](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json) or [decoderbug](https://github.com/debezium/postgres-decoderbufs)

Answer (score 2):

What you see is not WAL, but the output that the `test_decoding` logical decoding plugin produces.

There is no formal documentation fo rthat; read the source at `contrib/test_decoding/test_decoding.c`.

Note that that plugin is just for testing logical decoding, it is *not* intended for serious use.

The output you get from `pg_logical_slot_get_changes` depends on the plugin you use. Apart from `test_decoding`, PostgreSQL only ships with `pgoutput`, which is used for logical replication. Both of these might not be what you need, and you might have a look ad third-party software like wal2json.

Comment: All right, then, what *is* intended for serious use to read this data?  Because the documentation makes it look like `pg_logical_slot_get_changes` is The Right Way to get the change data.

Comment: I see. I have extended the answer.